# Having an unwanted white background while setting background color in NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, background-color, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField that is placed in IB. The delegate is set and its method

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
```

works fine.

What I like to achieve is to set the background color of my NSTextField to red as soon as the user starts typing.
But what I get is this:

[image]

You can see there's a fine red line on top of the text which tells me that

```
[textField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
```

is kind of working.

What I like to have instead is this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I could get rid of the white text background while typing into the NSTextField?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in starting time your textfield background color should be set clearcolor.Try it with clear color and then change.

Answer (score 0):

set it to `clearcolor` then set `new colour`